# ImageIO.read() returns null but not everytime

Tags: java, image

I'm trying to read images with ImageIO(url) but sometimes, it works perfectly and sometimes it returns me a null value for a reason I do not understand.

Here are some examples I've tried :

This url works : http://mars.jpl.nasa.gov/msl-raw-images/proj/msl/redops/ods/surface/sol/02350/opgs/edr/ncam/NLB_606105843EDR_F0750000NCAM00207M_.JPG

This url does not work : http://mars.nasa.gov/mer/gallery/all/1/n/4459/1N524036359EFFCRRLP1983L0M1-BR.JPG

I'm sure the url is good because I print it before.

My code :

```java
URL url = new URL(obj.getString("img_src"));
Image im = ImageIO.read(url);
```

For the first image, I can read and show the image, but when I try to read the second one, ImageIO.read() returns me a null value so I have a NullPointerException.

Comment: The second one goes through an HTTP redirect, which Java's URL class is not meant to handle by following the redirect like a browser would. Use a proper HTTP client library to handle these subtleties for you.